# R: heatmap.2 change color key

Tags: r, colors, heatmap

I have a question about the package `gplots`. I want to use the function `heatmap.2` and therefore I want to change my symmetric point in color key from 0 to 1. Normally when `symkey=TRUE` and you use the `col=redgreen()`, a colorbar is created where the colors are managed like this:

```
red = -2 to -0.5
black=-0.5 to 0.5
green= 0.5 to 2
```

Now i want to create a colorbar like this:

```
red= -1 to 0.8
black= 0.8 to 1.2
green= 1.2 to 3
```

Is something like this possible?

Thank you!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you look at [the heatmap.2 help file](http://hosho.ees.hokudai.ac.jp/~kubo/Rdoc/library/gplots/html/heatmap.2.html), it looks like you want the `breaks` argument. From the help file:

> `breaks` (optional) Either a numeric vector indicating the splitting points for binning x into colors, or a integer number of break points to be used, in which case the break points will be spaced equally between min(x) and max(x)

So, you use `breaks` to specify the cutoff points for each colour. e.g.:

```
library(gplots)

# make up a bunch of random data from -1, -.9, -.8, ..., 2.9, 3
# 10x10
x = matrix(sample(seq(-1,3,by=.1),100,replace=TRUE),ncol=10)

# plot. We want -1 to 0.8 being red, 0.8 to 1.2 being black, 1.2 to 3 being green.
heatmap.2(x, col=redgreen, breaks=c(-1,0.8,1.2,3))
```

The crucial bit is the `breaks=c(-1,0.8,1.2,3)` being your cutoffs.

Comment: Thank you Mathematical.coffee. Is there also a way to create some more overlap to the colors? Normally I use redgreen(75) which creates 75 colors!

Comment: As in, you want -1 to 0.8 to be varying shades of red, 0.8 to 1.2 varying shades of black (!), 1.2 to 3 varying shades of green? You can try adding more breaks to your `breaks`. e.g. `c( seq(-1,0.8,length=5),seq(0.8,1.2,length=5),seq(1.2,3,length=5)` to have approximately 5 shades for each break and so on. But you have to have the same number of shades for each break since `redgreen` scales linearly from red to green: if it's uneven you'll get bits of colours creeping into each other. But since `redgreen` is a gradual colour gradient, how will you tell when red stops and black starts, etc?